# What is wrong with the following batch code?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
for /L %%g in (1 1 2) do (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%l IN ('findstr /i "<h1>" output.txt')DO set name=%%l
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%l IN ("%name%") DO echo %%l
    FOR /F "delims=" %%m IN ('findstr /i /r ".*@.*\..*</label>" output.txt')DO set email=%%m
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%m IN ("%email%") DO echo %%m
)
```

In the above batch file It does not echo the value of name and email

But if I use,

```
@echo off
for /L %%g in (1 1 2) do (
call :sub
)
:sub
FOR /F "delims=" %%l IN ('findstr /i "<h1>" output.txt') DO set name=%%l
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%l IN ("%name%") DO echo %%l
FOR /F "delims=" %%m IN ('findstr /i /r ".*@.*\..*</label>" output.txt')DO set email=%%m
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%m IN ("%email%") DO echo %%m
```

It shows desired output with name and email.

Can you please explain why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block, you are setting the `name` and `email` variables *within* the `FOR` block. If you then want to access this value then you must have delayed expansion enabled. Without delayed expansion then the contents of the `FOR` loop are only parsed when the loop starts - at which point `name` and `email` do not have a value.

This edit should make the block work:

```
@echo off
REM Turn on the delayed expansion option.
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Note how "name" and "email" is wrapped in exclamation marks below.
REM This is delayed expansion notation.
for /L %%g in (1 1 2) do (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%l IN ('findstr /i "<h1>" output.txt')DO set name=%%l
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%l IN ("!name!") DO echo %%l
    FOR /F "delims=" %%m IN ('findstr /i /r ".*@.*\..*</label>" output.txt')DO set email=%%m
    FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=><" %%m IN ("!email!") DO echo %%m
)

ENDLOCAL
```

The second block works because each iteration of the loop calls the subroutine which causes the execution to parse on each pass.